# How to translate a text using button in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react, I am building a text utility app in it user can able to do some stuff in his text like change to uppercase, lowercase, translate etc. I am currently stuck on how to translate text using a button. I search a lot but not able to find any effective solution.

Here is my TextForm Component:

```
import counterpart from 'counterpart';
import Translate from 'react-translate-component';

counterpart.registerTranslations('hn',{
    textarea:{text}
});

counterpart.setLocale('en');


export default function TextForm(props) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const handleOnChange = (event) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
    }
    const handleUpChange = () => {
        let newText = text.toUpperCase();
        setText(newText);
    }
    const handleLoChange = () => {
        let newText = text.toLowerCase();
        setText(newText);
    }
    const handleTrChange = () => {
        <Translate content='textarea' component='textarea' />
        let newText = text
        setText(newText);

    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container my-3">
                <h1>{props.heading}</h1>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <textarea className="form-control" id="myBox" value={text} onChange={handleOnChange} placeholder="Enter here" rows="8"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary mx-1" onClick={handleUpChange}>Convert to Uppercase</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary mx-1" onClick={handleLoChange}>Convert to Lowercase</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary mx-1" onClick={handleTrChange}>Translate into Hindi</button>
            </div>
            <div className="container my-3">
                <h2>Your Text Summary</h2>
                <p>{text.split(' ').length} words and {text.length} characters</p>
                <p>{0.008 * text.split(' ').length} Minutes read</p>
                <h3>Preview</h3>
                <p>{text}</p>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: You could probably find a (paid) web service to translate text for you. Otherwise, search on the web for "i18n"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Button Component where you just hand over callback in this component. Button Component has to have useEffect hook where you call its callback with some params and conditions and then you should set state in any place what you want(usually it's local useState hook).

Comment: Could you possibly provide a code sample, so that the OP can better understand your solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).